# How to redeclare the annotation when inheriting a component in Modelica language?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to modify the annotation part when inheriting a component in Dymola, but I am not sure if Modelica supports this kind of manipulation.

My question is :

1. Does Modelica allow this kind of manipulation?
2. How should I modify the appearance if I can't modify the annotation part when inheriting a component?

Comment: This should be possible. What have you tried so far? What worked, what did not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to 'redraw' the icon of a model extending from another model you can use the following annotation

```
model ExtendedModel
  extends BaseModel annotation (
      IconMap(
        extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}, 
        primitivesVisible=false), 
      DiagramMap(
        extent={{-100,-100},{100,100}}, 
        primitivesVisible=true));

  end ExtendedModel;
```